# Android onCreate() not called with Notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I have met with interesting intent workflow handling.
I create a notification like this:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_default_holo_dark).setContentTitle("Мероприятие изменилось")
        .setContentText(eventToShow.valueAt(i).name + " " + eventToShow.valueAt(i).date).setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_EVENT_DISPLAY, eventToShow.valueAt(i).id);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(eventToShow.valueAt(i).id, mBuilder.build());
```

When notificataion is arrived to user, i expect that when he clicks on it MainActivity.class will handle this intent.
I process information about intent inside `MainActivity.onCreate()`.

Everything goes ok if i click on notification outside my app. Activity correctly processing this intent and shows what i expected.

But when i click on notification inside my app there is no new instanse of my `MainActivity.class` And `onCreate()` is not firing. I thought that it will be created new Instance of `MainActivity.class`

Can you explain me is this a default behavior and how should i handle this situation?

After testing my app i find next.

a) MainActivity -> get notification -> Close app -> Open app(MainActivity) -> press notification -> Notification opening new instance of MainActivity as expected.

b) MainActivity -> get notification -> press notification -> nothing is happened

Comment: Try with other flag in pending intent, maybe PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
Or you can set flags in intent Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. This should fire on create.

Comment: Can you get that `intent` in `onResume()` with `getIntent()` ?

Comment: @BobanS. tried both ideas but `Activity.onCreate()` is not firing.

Comment: @BobanS. for some reason when i call 
`int eventId = getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_EVENT_DISPLAY, -1);` from onResume it returns to me `-1`. When i expected to get value that i put ot it before.

Comment: Have you checked what you put in intent? Maybe `eventToShow.valueAt(i).id` is -1

Comment: @BobanS. No. i check it has value 14.

Comment: @BobanS.i update my answer with additional info. Maybe this can help you?

Comment: Have you tried to remove flags from pending intent ? `PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,resultIntent,0);`

Answer (score 1):

So i was researching about one day to fix that bug and here what i has found.
I am certainly sure that Android task system can give you headache.
It seem's that if Android decides that you are calling your intent from `non-Activity context`
it can be replased with new Intent.

`startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

And this `intent` will replace your original `intent` and you will not catch any data that you insert to it.

You can do next to prevent this situation. In your activity you should `Override` next method:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
int eventId = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_EVENT_DISPLAY, -1); 
}
```

And now you can handle this data